# Android Wear causing battery to quickly drain

Tags: notifications, battery, battery-life, standby, android-wear

I'm currently using a Zenwatch first generation alongside a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge on Android 6.0.1. Both devices are always fully updated.

The problem is that when my smartphone is connected to the Wear, the battery of the phone drains a lot faster than when it isn't connected. Since my phone is rooted, I'm using the BetterBatteryStats app in order to keep track of my device, and I noticed that when the smartphone is connected to the SmartWatch, the device almost never goes to the DeepSleep state, with the "Awake (Screen Off)" consuming almost all of the device processing time (this doesn't happen when the smartphone is disconnected to the SmartWatch).

My thinking is that the Notification Listener it's keeping the device from going into the DeepSleep mode, so the smartphone can send the received notifications to the SmartWatch. There's something I can do in order to get a better battery life when my device is connected to my SmartWatch?

Comment: This sounds like a wakelock issue. Ironically enough I started having the same issue with my Pebble yesterday. Is the phone rooted?

Comment: Yes, Ethan. The phone is rooted. Maybe this should be patched on Nougat? Have you tried contacting Google about it?

Comment: contacting Google isn't exactly possible. Do you have the "Wakelock Detector Free" app? Install it and add any apps that have more than a half hour holding a lock to the question. Obviously apps such as Spotify hold a lock if you are playing music through them, so those can be ignored.

Comment: I'm using it since yesterday. Weirdly, WhatsApp it's on top of all wakelocks _(I use that app a lot)_. There's nothing related to the Watch itself: Bluetooth; Android Wear; Google Play Services; Everything seems normal.